# Scout Eclipse TablePage Template

Tags: java, abstract-class, extension-methods, eclipse-scout

I want to create `AbstractTemplatePageWithTable` as template.

My problem is that when you create template :

```
 MyPageTemplateTablePage
           |
           ---> MyTable Extends AbstractTable
```

or in code

```
public abstract class MyPageTemplateTablePage extends AbstractExtensiblePageWithTable<MyTable> {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredTitle() {

    return TEXTS.get("bla bla");
  }


  public abstract class MyTable extends AbstractExtensibleTable {


  }
}
```

But When I create Page from this template it create "only" page.

```
 @PageData(MyPageTablePageData.class)
 public class MyPageTablePage extends MyPageTemplateTablePage {

   @Override
   protected String getConfiguredTitle() {

     return TEXTS.get("MyPage");
    }
  }
```

What I would want is that it is created :

```
@PageData(MyPageTablePageData.class)
 public class MyPageTablePage extends MyPageTemplateTablePage {

   @Override
   protected String getConfiguredTitle() {

     return TEXTS.get("MyPage");
    }

    @Order(10.0)
    public class table extends MyPageTemplateTablePage.MyTable {


    }
  }
```

Because when you create template, it should be user-friendly and provide table. Is there some annotation or something to convince scout-eclipse creator of class to create this table to.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to have wizards that suit all needs in the Scout SDK. Since Scout is plain Java you can organize the code as you like. There are 2 classes: `Table` and `TablePage` having the `Table` as inner class of the `TablePage` is convenient but not mandatory especially if you are preparing templates.

If you have logic on your table (like common methods or inner classes for menus or columns) I recommend you to create a first Table template:

```
public abstract class AbstractMyTable extends AbstractTable {
  //some custom logic.
}
```

Then you can define a TablePage template using Generic. You can even restrict the table to be from type `AbstractMyTable`

```
public abstract class AbstractMyTablePage<T extends AbstractMyTable> extends AbstractPageWithTable<T> {
  //some custom logic.
}
```

You might lose some of the SDK support using this pattern, but when you create a new table page you can modify your code to use your table template and your table page template:

```
@PageData(XxxxTablePageData.class)
public class XxxxTablePage extends AbstractMyTablePage<Table> {

  @Order(1000.0)
  public class Table extends AbstractMyTable {

  }
}
```